# C# Process.start opening application but not the file

Tags: c#

I have an IE plugin which adds buttons in a page where there are pdf links and opens them in a specific application when clicked.

Lets say I need to open a xyz.pdf file in abc.exe application. abc is not the default application for file type .pdf.

In one machine the below works

`Process p = Process.Start("pathtoabc.exe", "pathtoxyz.pdf");`

In another machine it only works if I make abc.exe as the default app and then use the below

`Process p = Process.Start("pathtoxyz.pdf");`

Can you give me any pointers please? I also tried using `ProcessStartInfo` with no change

Updates:

I tried using the default Acrobat reader with an argument

Argument for processstartinfo looks like this "C:\PDF Files\Professional-Letters-Guide.pdf"

FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"

Result - Acrobat reader opens but with an error message "File not found". The is available in the path though.

Solved:
It was a space in the Foldername.. solved it by enclosing the filename with quotes "\""

Thank you all for the suggestions.. they helped me think it through.

Comment: Did you read any error message?

Comment: no error message.. doesn't fail in the try catch.

Comment: No it will not be caught in try catch..   p.WaitForExit(); if (p.ExitCode != 0)
                { string exception = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();}

Comment: Thanks.. I will check this

Comment: To read exception in your start info you need to add these property too 
               UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,

Comment: What happend???

Comment: I tried the suggestions.. Process exited with condition code 0.. still no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried qualifying the Process.StartInfo.Arguments value with quotes and the full path to the file?  What about the WorkingDirectory property? Also, the previous assertion regarding confirmation of the application being called supporting command line parameters is absolutely valid.  You can be fooled into thinking that it does due to operating system file extension associations specific to a machine.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the `Process.Start` is passed to the application you are trying to start and it wont open the file using this application "pathtoabc.exe" unless the application "pathtoabc.exe" accepts the file name as a startup argument.

So you need to check if the application you are trying to use supports this kind of argument.

Comment: It says it works on one machine, so if this is the same application it should work. However the question is vague on details.

Comment: Maybe it's already the default application on the first machine.

Comment: In the first machine, the application is not set as default yet still the code manages to open the file in the specific app. It actually worked when I just used the dlls from my bin in both the machines. It stopped opening the file when I created a setup project and installed using the msi.

Comment: @Sathya open up command line and check? `path/to/abc.exe path/to/file.pdf` If it starts up correctly then you're okay but if not then you have to check how to boot up this application with the file posted as a command line argument

Comment: @m.rogalski Thank you. I should have checked this before posting.Not in the machine. Will check and update